# xamarin Ios add UIView to ContainerView

Tags: ios, xamarin, constraints, syncfusion, sfcalendar

I need help align a Subview in ContainerView. I tried to add contraints but it messed up everything so I tried FluentLayout (https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout)

My Code looks like this:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            SFCalendar calendar = new SFCalendar();
            containerView.AddSubview(calendar);

            containerView.AtBottomOf(this.View);
            containerView.AtTopOf(this.View);
            containerView.WithSameWidth(this.View);

            calendar.AtBottomOf(containerView);
            calendar.AtTopOf(containerView);
            calendar.WithSameWidth(containerView);
        }
```

But in the end my Calendar is cut off a bit, what i am doing wrong here?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use the Autolayout, you should disable the `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. So set this two controls property to False will make a trick, moreover you should correct your usage:

```
containerView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

SFCalendar calendar = new SFCalendar();
containerView.AddSubview(calendar);

calendar.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

View.AddConstraints(containerView.AtBottomOf(this.View),
containerView.AtTopOf(this.View),
containerView.WithSameWidth(this.View));


containerView.AddConstraints(calendar.AtBottomOf(containerView),
calendar.AtTopOf(containerView),
calendar.WithSameWidth(containerView));
```

But I recommend you to use the native Constraints to do this, also it seems you want to make this `containerView` full screen. Add its leading, trailing, top, bottom will be better:

```
SFCalendar calendar = new SFCalendar();
containerView.AddSubview(calendar);

containerView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
containerView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
containerView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(TopLayoutGuide.GetBottomAnchor()).Active = true;
containerView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
containerView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(BottomLayoutGuide.GetTopAnchor()).Active = true;

calendar.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
calendar.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
calendar.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.TopAnchor).Active = true;
calendar.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
calendar.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

We have created a sample by using `NSLayoutConstraint`. In this you can the change the layout size, but we cannot access the `fluentlayout` in this. please find the sample from the following [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Calendar_screen_sample305356491)